# aws ecs 403 error to login private registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to login to Quay with ECS.
Quay is a private registry docker.

I followed this documentation but I have also a 403 error: "{\"error\": \"Permission Denied\"}".

I put this code in `/etc/ecs/ecs.config`:

```
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=docker
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={"https://quay.io/": { "username": "xxxxxx","password":"xxxxx","email": "."}}
```

And I've reboot the ecs services but it's not working.

Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.quay.io/issues/ecs-auth-failure.html) points out to a slightly different content of `/etc/ecs/ecs.conf`:

```
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_TYPE=dockercfg
ECS_ENGINE_AUTH_DATA={"https://quay.io": {"auth": "YOURAUTHTOKENFROMDOCKERCFG", "email": "user@example.com"}}
```

It uses `dockercfg` and a token rather than username/password.

The `dockercfg` is described in the documentation page "[I'm authorized but I'm still getting 403s](https://docs.quay.io/issues/auth-failure.html)"

> docker stores the credentials it uses for push and pull in a file typically placed at `$HOME/.dockercfg`.
>
> If you are executing docker in another environment (scripted docker build, virtual machine, makefile, virtualenv, etc), docker will not be able to find the `.dockercfg` file and will fail.

As the [OP Mathieu Perochon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6113991/mathieu-perochon) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339826/aws-ecs-403-error-to-login-private-registry/37340062?noredirect=1#comment62258880_37340062), this is also linked to the environment version of the [Amazon Machine Image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html):

> I have upgrade my [AMI (Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) and it's working

Comment: thanks for reply, i've tried this configuration but i've same error

Comment: @MathieuPerochon Then the last sentence of my answer might be relevant in your boot2docker VM context.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a newbie to this forum and my english is not very good.. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply @VonC. i've resolved my problem. i have upgrade my AMI (Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux) and it's working.

Link to good AMI : https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00U6QTYI2/